# How to parse XOP/MTOM SOAP response using java?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, mtom, xop

I just want to know, is there any simple way for parsing  MTOM/XOP SOAP response. 
The problem is that I use plain HTTP to send soap message and javax.xml for parsing response. But some services responds me with mulipart/related and it    requires much more complex logic to parse it (performance matters). 
So I wonder may I somehow take advantage of apache cxf, apache axiom or any other library for parsing MTOM/XOP SOAP response?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[These unit tests](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/branches/2.7.x-fixes/api/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/attachment/AttachmentDeserializerTest.java) show you how to use CXF to extract attachments out of an MTOM message.  I'll inline one of the tests in case this link doesn't exist in the future:

```
private MessageImpl msg;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    msg = new MessageImpl();
    Exchange exchange = new ExchangeImpl();
    msg.setExchange(exchange);
}

@Test
public void testDeserializerMtom() throws Exception {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("mimedata");
    String ct = "multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\"; "
                + "start=\"<soap.xml@xfire.codehaus.org>\"; "
                + "start-info=\"text/xml; charset=utf-8\"; "
                + "boundary=\"----=_Part_4_701508.1145579811786\"";

    msg.put(Message.CONTENT_TYPE, ct);
    msg.setContent(InputStream.class, is);

    AttachmentDeserializer deserializer = new AttachmentDeserializer(msg);
    deserializer.initializeAttachments();

    InputStream attBody = msg.getContent(InputStream.class);
    assertTrue(attBody != is);
    assertTrue(attBody instanceof DelegatingInputStream);

    Collection<Attachment> atts = msg.getAttachments();
    assertNotNull(atts);

    Iterator<Attachment> itr = atts.iterator();
    assertTrue(itr.hasNext());

    Attachment a = itr.next();
    assertNotNull(a);

    InputStream attIs = a.getDataHandler().getInputStream();

    // check the cached output stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(attBody, out);
    assertTrue(out.toString().startsWith("<env:Envelope"));

    // try streaming a character off the wire
    assertTrue(attIs.read() == '/');
    assertTrue(attIs.read() == '9');
}
```

In your case, the `ct` will come from the content type header of the response.  The `"mimedata"` will be the content of the response.

Comment: I've done it in the same way. Just don't have a time for sharing. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Dear Daniel,
Could you please guide me about content-type related with question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455584/manually-parse-mtom-message

Answer (score 6):

No need to use **CXF**, the standard **javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart** class do the job and it's very easy to use (also to create MTOM request).

Here a very simple sample to decode parts of a MTOM response:

```
MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(data, contentType));
int count = mp.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
    bp.saveFile(filepath + "_" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and solved as @Nicolas Albert

```
public byte[] mimeParser(InputStream isMtm) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    try {
        MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(isMtm,
                ct));
        int count = mp.getCount();
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            if (!Part.ATTACHMENT
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())
                    && !StringUtils.isNotBlank(bodyPart.getFileName())) {
                continue; // dealing with attachments only
            }
            bodyPart.writeTo(baos);
        }

        byte[] attachment = baos.toByteArray();
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("E:/wss/attachment.zip"), attachment);
        return attachment;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (baos != null) {
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What `ct` is in the `ByteArrayDataSource()`? From where that content type should come?