# MTOM Message parsing

Tags: java, wcf, mtom

I am getting the below response from a WCF service

```
--uuid:57cad2b9-196b-4780-9643-cab6131bed98+id=43
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><DownloadFileResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><DownloadFileResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OneC_GenericUploadMessageContract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:EncryptedFileUploadID i:nil="true"/><a:FileContentId i:nil="true"/><a:FileException i:nil="true"/><a:FileExternalURL i:nil="true"/><a:FileLocation i:nil="true"/><a:FileName>176827.jpeg</a:FileName><a:FileURL>C9533C2F-AC59-E411-9405-005056853C65\_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000_56_9_2016_15_11_4_13_636010818640138255.jpeg</a:FileURL><a:FileUploadId>0</a:FileUploadId><a:Filestatus i:nil="true"/><a:OutgoingFile><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/636029758108722711" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></a:OutgoingFile></DownloadFileResult></DownloadFileResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:57cad2b9-196b-4780-9643-cab6131bed98+id=43
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636029758108722711>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

-----binary content here----
```

i tried parsing this using [How to parse XOP/MTOM SOAP response using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150004/how-to-)

I am getting boundary missing exception. I am not seeing any boundary specified for this response.
Am i missing something or is this message not properly send?