# How do I extract a Gzip attachment in a SOAP MTOM webservice using NiFi?

Tags: soap, apache-nifi, mtom

How do I extract a Gzip attachment in a SOAP MTOM webservice using NiFi? What are the processors to use to do that.

Comment: is it possible to provide a small example of the service response?

Comment: You can generate a SOAP MTOM attachment using this link:  https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/attachments.html

Comment: I also found this links that you might find very useful using java to extract attachment from Soap MTOM webservice and the Java could be use in the NiFi's groovy processor:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150004/how-to-parse-xop-mtom-soap-response-using-java